# Derive the conversion factor from SI to Geometric units

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, units, unit-conversion, absolute-units

In the geometrized system of units, $G = c = 1$. This directly gives us the definitions for second and kilogram in this system, as $1\:s = c_0\:m$ and $1\:kg = G_0c_0^{-2}\:m$, where I have used the subscript, $0$, to denote dimensionless numbers, corresponding to the values of those quantities in SI. For example, $c_0 = 299792458$ (no units). Using these, I was trying to derive the conversion or scaling factors for other physical quantities. For quantities, having dimensions in the three base units of Mass, Length and Time (in SI), the conversion is straightforward, as we have definitions for $kg$ and $s$.

For quantities, involving other base units, like ampere, candela or kelvin, I cannot seem to proceed. The derivations seem circular. For example, in electromagnetism, to get the conversion factor for electric charge, I must know the conversion factor for the electric constant, which itself depends on the unit of electric charge.

I have looked into the [Wikipedia page on Geometrized Units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrized_unit_system), and the reference provided therein (Dr. Robert Wald’s book on General Relativity), but I cannot find any derivation in that reference. Same goes for a few introductory General Relativity textbooks, that I have. Can someone point out, what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get charge also in units of length you also need to fix $\epsilon_0$, a common *choice* is $4\pi\epsilon_0=1$ (see the Wikipedia page you quoted). This gives $1 A = c_0^{-3}\sqrt{\frac{G_0}{4\pi (\epsilon_0)_0}}$, where $(\epsilon_0)_0$ is the numerical value of $\epsilon_0$ in SI units.

Comment: Following your answer, I can now show that $$1 C = \frac{1}{c_0^2}\sqrt{\frac{G_0}{4\pi(\epsilon_0)_0}}\:m$$. This gives a dimensionally consistent conversion. Just one more query: Should there be some scaling factor (an additional number) here, as well, or is this equation sufficient to perform numerical conversions?

Comment: So, the reason, why I cannot derive the conversion factors for quantities in EM, without fixing $\epsilon_0$ or other similar quantity, is that Ampere is a fundamental unit, which cannot be represented by the 3 base units? Is it like trying to solve for 4 variables (MLTA), with only 3 constraints (on M, L and T), and is thus an underspecification? I apologise for saying, “one more query” earlier, but this is just for reassuring myself.